# POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500

Tags: botframework

I started getting a basic QnaDialog code working using .Net and the BotFramework is Microsoft.Bot.Builder.3.16.0.38344. I have been trying to get very basic functionality of QNA but it keeps throwing 500. I tried to change the database to DocumentDB as suggested by others and I can see that the items are created there in db but just that the call is not succeeding.

This is what I have:

```
[Serializable]
public class QnaDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{

    public QnaDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for that", 0.5)))
    {
    }

 }
```

Not sure if I am missing anything. Help is appreciated

Here is the exception:

{ "message": "An error has occurred.", "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException", "stackTrace": " at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.QnAMakerService.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.Extensions.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.QnAMakerDialog.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog1.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.d__23.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: were you working off a particular sample?

Comment: Also, here's an example I had ran through, before v4 was released as the main samples in Azure portal. It's utilizing qnamaker in v3: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/666